# StringBuilder deleteCharAt() function " String index out of range : 6 "

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

[Code and Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt1Zg.jpg)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn1Wd.jpg)

hey Guys see the Image and help me out to sort out this issue

It is the first code and it runs perfectly but when i use the same approach in the blow code it have some error
" For error detail open image link "

```
String str = "Samaarth";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
sb.deleteCharAt(3);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

This is where the error start and the error is because of DeleteCharAt() function but in the above code this function works perfectly but here it is not 
IDK why so please help me out to sort our this issue

```
String str= "aaabccddd";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);

for (int i = 0; i < str.length() -1; i++) {
    if (sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(i + 1)) {
        sb.deleteCharAt(i);
        //sb.deleteCharAt(i+1);
    }
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Use a pen and a paper, and write the value of sb and i at each iteration. And you'll understand.

Comment: Not related to iteration logic . I have found the real problem it is in condition area of for loop. there i use str.length() in place of sb.length(). The  String Builder's String length get vaied everytime i delete char that's why it have problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using for loop and you are actually changing/mutating StringBuilder instance at the same time, so the .length() will not be fixed and eventually you will try to reach non-existing index in your for loop and exception will be thrown.

EDIT:

Add these two lines inside your for loop if statement, just before you invoke deleteCharAt() method:

```
System.out.println("Value of i is: " + i);
System.out.println("StringBuilder length is: " + sb.length());
```

"i" represents index you are trying to delete, and sb.length() will display actual length of the StringBuilder.

Comment: it works only when i use sb.length() cause the length of string get changed everytime but when i use str.length() the length remains the same and the loop goes out of bound . Anyways Thank for your help

Comment: one more help sir

Comment: when i am trying to access the last '' d '' character in my defined string then it gives me error like that . code looks good to me even logic as well but i cannot find out error so help me out with that     here is the code                                                           for(int i=0;i<sb.length()-1;i++)
  {
   System.out.println(sb.length() + " Value of i ="+i);
   
   if(sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(i+1))
   {
    System.out.println(" Char at i " +sb.charAt(i) + " Char at i+1" +sb.charAt(i+1));
    sb.deleteCharAt(i);
    sb.deleteCharAt(i+1);
    i=0;
   }
 
  }

Comment: Can you take a picture like that first one, so I can see code and the error that it gives and post link here in the comments.

Comment: @SamarthSaxena Easiest way to fix this is to start from the end of string and go forward, so you won't have issues with index being out of bounds, try this: https://pastebin.com/KMP2LaGc

Answer (score 2):

Samarath, you both modify the string and advance the counter. 
This is wrong. Consider the string "aaaa"
This is what your code does:

*i = 0: you find the duplicate, remove it. The string becomes "aaa".
Then you advance the position: i becomes 1*

*i = 1: the string is "a|aa" (the vertical bar shows the position).
You find the duplicate at position 1. You kill it, the string
becomes "aa", but you advance the position one again: i becomes 2*

*At this step the `for` loop ends and your string is "aa".*

Instead the algorithm should use while loop: "while there are duplicates, kill them!"

```
String str= "aaabccddd";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);

int i = 0;
while (i < sb.length()-1) {
    if (sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(i + 1)) {
        sb.deleteCharAt(i);
        // Do not increment -- kill all duplicates
    } else {
        // Either not a duplicate, or all duplicated killed
        // Advance one char
        i++;
    }
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

The output is `abcd`.

If you are inclined to use `for` loop, then iterate in the reverse order:

```
String str= "aaabccddd";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);

for (int i = sb.length()-1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(i - 1)) {
        // Note charAt(i - 1) - we compare with the preceding character
        sb.deleteCharAt(i);
        // The string squeezes by one char, but the decremented position
        // will follow
    } 
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

The output is `abcd`